# TeamCity REST API - update 'settings' for build configuration

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to use the TeamCity REST API to update settings against a build configuration. Specifically, the `checkoutDirectory` that in the UI is in the "Version Control Settings->Additional Options->Checkout directory" textbox...

[image]

The [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest/edit-build-configuration-settings.html) talks about updating the "parameters", but not the settings.

If I do a GET on `/app/rest/buildTypes/<id>`, the results include both settings and parameters...

[image]

I've tried various combinations of PUT request to try to update this, but having no luck.

Interestingly, if I do a GET on `/app/rest/buildTypes/<id>/parameters`, I get this...

[image]

Which includes the ID in the URL.

But if I do `/app/rest/buildTypes/<id>/settings`, I get this...

[image]

Which *doesn't* include the ID. Not sure if that's a bug - or I've completely misunderstood the scope of these settings, and they're global, not per build config - but that's certainly not what I'm seeing in the UI.

Any ideas how to use the REST API to update these settings?